# Как проверить с помощью js поддерживает ли браузер css-функию?

Tags: css, javascript

Например поддерживает ли calc или префексный -webkit-calc?

Comment: Проверить, что за браузер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поковырявшись в [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) нашел такой способ:

```
function check_calc()
{
   var el=document.body.createElement('div');
   el.style.cssText='width:calc(10px)';
   return !!el.style.length;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, только поправьте немного вашу функцию, оставьте el или div